# Find next ocurrence of values - COUNTIF is too slow

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to speed up a COUNTIFS formula in a table I have.
The table is over 60k rows and the COUNTIFS has three conditions. The formula right now looks like this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS([Vessel],[@Vessel],[Date],">"&[@Date],[ETA],"<="&[@ETA]+20)=0,[@Arrived]=1,[@Sailed]=1,[@Date]<MAX([Date])),1,0)
```

The problem is that the calculation takes a very long time and it triggers everytime something change, even the filter. I don't want to turn calculations to manual in this sheet.

The purpose of the formula is to find the next occurence of the vessel in the line, the ETA can be slightly changed from day to day or the same ship can appear months later. I need to confirm if the vessel appears with the same ETA (or up to 20 days of difference) on another day.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: I might second the macro idea as any formula that has 60k formulas each effectively containing 180k if statements will take a while to run.

Comment: I'm trying to change the formula to not use an array, this way I can have it updating as I change things and don't have to use VBA.

Comment: Is there a specific way the data is sorted?  If all the lines for the same ship together you could speed it up.  If you just need to find a similar date somewhere in the list I think its going to involve a large array formula or a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try building this as a macro instead, that way you would have control over when it executes.

Here is a start on a method for doing this.  It gets the job done but breaks on an error on/after the last line is processed.  Edit : Fixed and tested

```
Public Sub shipcheck()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long
Dim y As String
Dim counter As Long



For x = 2 To Range("A85536").End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming data has headers
y = Cells(x, 1)  ' This assumes your vessel is in the first column
counter = x + 1
 Do
    If cells(counter,1) = "" Then Exit Do
    If y = Cells(counter, 1) Then
        If Cells(x, 2) <> Cells(counter, 2) Then   'This assumes your date is the second column
            If DateDiff("d", Cells(x, 3), Cells(counter, 3)) > 20 Then ' this assumes ETA is your third column
                Cells(x, 4) = 1     'This assumes the positive test is the fourth column
                Cells(counter, 4) = 1
                Exit Do

            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
 counter = counter + 1
 Loop

Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please excuse my terrible coding skills, I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to run this.

Comment: I'm trying to build a formula because the column is the last check that I do. Every time I update the database I have to clean the data and having to run the macro every time I change something will be as bad as it is now.

Comment: Running it when you change a set of data seems to me better than having it update with every cell that is updated and filter is applied.  But you know your workflow better than I do.  Best of luck.